# Selecting from pg_stat_user_indexes using superuser

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to setup some custom monitoring for postgres and one of the metrics I want to see is the index usage from `pg_stat_user_indexes`. I have multiple databases, each of them have indexes and I want a single `metrics` role that has access to all of them.

The problem is that when I `select * from pg_stat_user_indexes` using the `metrics` role I see no results. But if I select with the individual database role I see the stats just fine.

The `metrics` role is a superuser with Bypass RLS. I tried looking at `pg_stat_all_indexes` but I can see only `pg_*` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#pg-stat-all-indexes-view

> The **pg_stat_all_indexes** view will contain one row for each index in
>   the **current database**, showing statistics about accesses to that
>   specific index. The pg_stat_user_indexes and pg_stat_sys_indexes views
>   contain the same information, but filtered to only show user and
>   system indexes respectively.

emphasis mine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to be connected to the specific database you want to monitor (not to postgres db) in order to see those stats.

Bizarre.. would have at least expected to see them all in `pg_stat_all_indexes` - it should have been named `pg_stat_all_indexes_for_current_database_plus_pg_catalog` - I know.. but `pg_stat_all_indexes` is not all indexes at all..